# Internal error (specific information not available): [client 10.132.46.153:54838] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server *** referer

Tags: node.js

I am currently using Node Js Application (6.10.3) in a combination of Apache Web server 2.4.23.Application is running from last one year on production . Suddenly for some users we are getting below response on screen

Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

While investigating logs we are getting below logs error in web application

Internal error (specific information not available): [client 10.132.46.153:54838] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 101:8000, referer: http://abc/

while googling error we come to know one solution need to add below property on web server http conf

SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

Below its not working for us. below is the http configuration

ServerName abc.com 
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://abc:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://abc:8000/
ErrorLog logs/file_error.log
CustomLog logs/file_access_log combined

Also wanted to add one point that only for some user we are getting this issue . Any help would be proffered .

Comment: Did you find a solution/root cause for this issue?